# How to make automatic twitter dm bot

Tags: java, python, twitter, automation, bots

I was wondering whether it would be possible to make a bot that would send a message to an existing list of twitter users. If it is possible, then what coding language should i use and how would i even start? I have access to twitter api if that helps.

Comment: Read https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation - you should not be sending automated Direct Messages without explicit permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you will need to use your Twitter API keys.
I think the most common way to code a Twitter bot is to do it in Python. Here's a good tutorial https://realpython.com/twitter-bot-python-tweepy/

Hope it'll help you :)